# Ping doesn't work, but I can browse through the internet

Tags: terminal, internet, ping

Pinging my default gateway is working properly and I can browse google and facebook in my browser. But, `ping google.com` and `ping facebook.com` on my terminal are not working.

```
PING google.com (216.58.220.46) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Is just stuck. I also tried to reinstall `resolvconf` with `sudo apt-get remove --purge resolvconf && sudo apt-get install --reinstall resolvconf`. But still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Outgoing ICMP (ping) is probably blocked by your firewall or gateway. That you are able to browse the Internet does not need ICMP (ping) to be working. You also might have a proxy configured which allows you to only surf the web.

Comment: any way to get around this?